# Iterating through columns when they are nan

Tags: python, pandas

I'm iterating through the cells in a column and some of those cells might be empty. Printing some of those values will give the following output (The number indicates which cell/index I'm on):

> 204 ['https://www.somelink.com/random-serial-number-5a4sd5as4d', 'https://www.somelink.com/random-serial-number-asdaws8dqw89d4', 'https://www.somelink.com/random-serial-number-awd89qw89d4qw']

> 205 nan

I then iterate through each of those items and replace them with certain keywords.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    file = pd.read_csv('DATA_TABLE_RAW.csv')
    id_column = file['ID'].str.split('/')
    id_result = id_column.str.get(3)
    id_result = id_result.str.split('-')
    id_result = id_result.str.get(0)
     
    bucketColumn = file['Bucket'].str.split(', ')
    
    bucket = [''] * len(bucketColumn)
    
    for index, column in enumerate(bucketColumn):

        print(index, column)
        if (pd.isna(column)): # problem line
            print(index, " is Empty")
   
        for item in column:
            # print(index)
            if ('5a4sd5as4d' in item):
                bucket[index] += 'Integerity, '

            elif ('asdaws8dqw89d4' in item):
                bucket[index] += 'Resources, '
    
            elif ('awd89qw89d4qw' in item):
                bucket[index] += 'Class, '

# then take that data and save to an excel file.
```

The issue is that because some fields will be empty and appear as `nan` I cannot iterate through it and I get the error:

> for item in column:
> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

So my plan was to just catch columns that are empty and not iterate over them. On the line I marked `# problem line` I tried using `isna()` but that returns the following error:

> if (pd.isna(column)):
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Also tried using `pd.isnull(column)` which gave the same error:

> if (pd.isnull(column)):
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried doing `if (not column):` but that doesn't catch when 205 is empty. or `if (len(column) == 0):` and that also doesn't catch it. Is there a way to detect if a column/array is empty without running into these issues?

Comment: Try `pandas.isnull` -- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, the issue arises since sometimes when the value is not `nan`, it is a list of values, and `pd.isna` will return a list, so you can't directly use an `if` there. Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

def main():
    file = pd.read_csv('DATA_TABLE_RAW.csv')
    id_column = file['ID'].str.split('/')
    id_result = id_column.str.get(3)
    id_result = id_result.str.split('-')
    id_result = id_result.str.get(0)
     
    bucketColumn = file['Bucket'].str.split(', ')
    
    bucket = [''] * len(bucketColumn)
    
    for index, column in enumerate(bucketColumn):

        print(index, column)
        if (column == np.nan): # if condition changed
            print(index, " is Empty")
        else:
            for item in column:
                # print(index)
                if ('5a4sd5as4d' in item):
                    bucket[index] += 'Integerity, '

                elif ('asdaws8dqw89d4' in item):
                    bucket[index] += 'Resources, '
    
                elif ('awd89qw89d4qw' in item):
                    bucket[index] += 'Class, '

# then take that data and save to an excel file.
```

Another simple solution would just be to do (a bit hacky though):

```
df.fillna("")
```